# Array splitting in sub-arrays of consecutive elements

Tags: array, matlab

I want to split an array in sub-arrays of consecutive elements. For example, for the array:

```
a=[1 2 3 6 7 9 10 15]
```

I want an output `1 2 3`, `6 7`, `9 10`, `15`.

I think that the natural choice is to use a `struct` for this:

```
[v,x] = find(diff(a)>1) %find "jumps"

xx=[0 x length(a)] 

for ii=1:length(xx)-1
   cs{ii}=a(xx(ii)+1:xx(ii+1)); %output struct array
end
```

> v =
>
> ```
>  1     1     1
> ```
>
> x =
>
> ```
>  3     5     7
> ```
>
> xx =
>
> ```
>  0     3     5     7     8
> ```

The code works correctly but I was wondering if there are smarter ways to do this.

Comment: You're using a cell array, not a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should preallocate the `cs` cell array:

```
[v,x] = find(diff(a)>1); %find "jumps"
xx = [0 x length(a)];
cs = cell(length(a)+1,1);
for ii = 1:length(xx)-1
   cs{ii} = a(xx(ii)+1:xx(ii+1));
end
```

Style comments:

- Try to keep consistent formatting, either put spaces around all equal signs, or around none.
- Terminate statements with a semicolon to prevent your function producing output to the command window.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of accessing array's elements via colon notation. For example, if you need to extract the first three elements of an array `a=[7 9 6 4 5 8]`, you type `b=a(1:3)`. These statements are equivalent `a(1:1:3)=a(1:3)=a([1 2 3])` which return the first three elements. In your example, it is a matter of controlling the indexes for colon notation, therefore,

```
a=[1 2 3 6 7 9 10 15];
b=a(1:3) % --> [1 2 3]
c=a(4:5) % --> [6 7]
d=a(6:7) % --> [9 10]
e=a(end) % --> [15]
```